# Add subdomains that redirect to different local servers using nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

After reading a few instructions and finding only half answers, here goes a small request:

I have a dynamic ip with a ddns service pointing "example.com" to my ip. 
Locally, my router redirects the access port to a win2016 server on which I run Nginx and I am trying to configure it so that I can access different local servers (server1:port1, server1:port2, server2:port3) using "subdomain.example.com".

So I am missing something, as all I managed to do is redirect the main example.com to anything I want OR redirect "example.com/name" to a local server.

What should I do to be able to access "server1:port1, server1:port2, server2:port3" using "subdomain1.example.com, subdomain2.example.com, subdomain3.example.com"

I am pulling my hair out.

Comment: Please show your current nginx configuration of these "redirects".

Comment: At the moment I deleted all entries I tried in nginx.conf. I only have left: 

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
 listen 80;
 server_name example.com;

 location / {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:port1;
 }   

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

}